# $L/F$ extension fields, $|L|=p^2$ elements, $F=\mathbb{F}_{p}$ then $[L:F]=2$.

Tags: field-theory

Let $L/F$ extension fields. If $|L|=p^2$ and $F=\mathbb{F}_{p}$. Why $[L:F]=2$? (degree) I cannot identify the basis formed by two elements of $L$.

Comment: A counting argument works (you don't need to construct a basis at all)

Answer (score 0):

A counting argument works fine. There must exist a (finite) basis, and there must be two elements since if $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is a basis then each element can be expressed uniquely as $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i e_i$ with $a_i \in \mathbb{F}_p$, so $n=2$.

To *construct* a basis: take $\{1, \alpha\}$ where $\alpha \in L \setminus F$. I'll leave it to you to show that this forms a basis.

Comment: why $n=2$? I can't not see this :(

Comment: If there are $n$ elements in a basis for a vector space $V/\mathbb{F}_p$, how many elements are in the vector space $V$?

Comment: oh!  thanks! exists $p$ posibilities for each $a_i$, then exists $p^n$ elements in the vector space $V$ with a basis with $n$ elements.
Therefore $n=2$